# Using link_with makes my project failed, CocoaPods 0.37

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, target

All my targets use the same libraries, so I use link_with to make my podfile neat. But to my surprise the project compiled failed. Xcode complains it can't find some files in pod, e.g.

> diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory diff:
>   /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory error: The sandbox is not in
>   sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods
>   installation.

And

> 'DDLog.h' file not found

I run pod install again and clean xcode again and again. But no luck. I was not able to figure out why. From what I can see cocopods only changed shellScript for each target to one single Pods-resources.sh, which is what link_with is supposed to do, right?

```
shellScript = "\"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-CloudPhone/Pods-"my target"-resources.sh\"\n";
shellScript = "\"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-resources.sh\"\n";
```

Is this a cocopods's bug? I am using latest one 0.37 and now I went back to specify each target individually.

Update:

CocoaPods 1.0 has removed link_with in favour of [abstract_target](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.0/)

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a pods bug. The pods doesnot update the script location, when a project specify target specific configuration initially and later tries to combine it.

To fix, go to Build phases->Embedd pod framework-> update the script file location to reflect the universal pod folder (like /Pods/Pods-frameworks.sh"). [You can navigate in finder to find exactly where the sh is present]. Remove any other script which doesn't reflect in physical folder. Now the project should compile.

Comment: Super answer. All I needed to change was Build phases->Embedd pod framework-> "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/PhysicalLoacationOfThePods-frameworks.sh

Answer (score 3):

Quick solution: remove `Embed Pod Frameworks` and run `pod install` again

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same error. Just want to add to Sukitha's Answer.

Go to **build phase** -> **Embed pod framework** -> `$SRCROOT`

Be sure to check that this **SRSCROOT** file block correctly leads up to the `frameworks.h` file.

You will need to edit in order to correct issue.

Cheers